# Difference between apt and apt-get

Tags: apt

I'm on my journey towards Ubuntu and Linux in general after 20 years of Windows. I'm still trying to understand the different concepts.

I've been reading a lot about the OS the last few weeks and gradually learning about all kind of features. Specially about the application management part. During some testing I've noticed a difference in the commands `apt-get` and just using `apt`. Using `apt install package` I get a nice little progress bar, `apt-get install package` on the other hand seems to be doing the same except the progress bar.

Can anyone verify or let me know if that's indeed the only difference or is there more than meets the eye?